# SQL return the max version of each documents

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have duplicated document number, value and version
I need to return only the lines with the document with the max version

```
Document|value|version
A20|100|1
A20|200|2
A24|100|1
A24|300|2
A24|200|3
A25|100|1
A26|100|1
```

expected result to return only the last document version

```
Document|value|version
A20|200|2
A24|200|3
A25|100|1
A26|100|1
```

Here is what I did but it return everything and not only the max version of the documents

```
SELECT MAX(FACT.VERSION), FACT.DOCUMENT, FACT.VALUE
FROM PUBLIC.FACT FACT
GROUP BY FACT.DOCUMENT, FACT.VALUE, FACT.VERSION
```

Comment: Which is your database engine?

Comment: Why are you grouping by the column you want to aggregate?

Comment: You don't want to aggregate data, but keep original rows. You can do this with an anylytic function (e.g. `MAX OVER`) or with a subquery. What DBMS are you using? You should always tag your SQL requests with the DBMS you are using in order to only get answers that work for you.

Comment: `GROUP BY ___` means one result row per ___. Your `GROUP BY` clause says "give me one result row per document, value, and version. This is every single row in the table, because they all differ in document and version. The maximum version of a single row is of course the row's version. This is what you see when you run your query.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FACT.* 
FROM PUBLIC.FACT FACT
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT FACT2.DOCUMENT, MAX(FACT2.VERSION) AS HVERSION
FROM PUBLIC.FACT FACT2
GROUP BY FACT2.DOCUMENT) HV
ON HV.DOCUMENT = FACT.DOCUMENT
AND HV.HVERSION = FACT.VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question on SO and appears in business frequently. It's helpful to think of it as a pattern.

1. Identify the max version by grouping field(s) in a CTE or subquery or temp table
2. Use the recordset from 1. to join to the original table on the grouping fields and max_version = version

Like so:

```
SELECT X.*
FROM PUBLIC.FACT X
INNER JOIN (SELECT DOCUMENT, MAX(VERSION) AS MAX_VERSION
            FROM PUBLIC.FACT
            GROUP BY DOCUMENT) Y ON X.DOCUMENT = Y.DOCUMENT AND X.VERSION = Y.MAX_VERSION;
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e301dbadcbfa632ac1b56c4f15a9c403)

Comment: max_version synthax error

Comment: @John, corrected

Comment: You will need to be significantly more clear than that and either edit your post for additional details to the problem or create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FACT.Document, FACT.value, FACT.version
From (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Document order by FACT.value DESC) as rn
        FROM PUBLIC.FACT 
     ) FAC
WHER rn = 1
```

Comment: I'm curious if this will always return the max document version if two versions of the same document have the same value.